# KVM solution for 2 computers to switch 6 monitors (2x3) with DisplayPort connections

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-port, kvm

I am trying to find a solution to be able to KVM two computers, both with two DisplayPort outputs (two video cards on one PC and a docking station with two ports) to a monitor array connected with two DisplayPort hubs that join three monitors (2x3) and one keyboard and one mouse.

I'm not even sure if the type of KVM I am looking for even exists.  Possible scenarios in my mind are:

1. KVM that has two inputs for each computer (2x2) and two outputs, or
2. A KVM model that can link multiple switches in a master/slave relationship so when the master is switched, the slave will switch as well.

Ideally, the KVM solution would support DisplayPort 1.2 or higher and would cost between $100 and $500 USD.